# Recursive id generation returning wrong value, though generates correct one?

Tags: java, recursion, sequence

I'm creating a program where it stores a custom Object into a LinkedList for reference, then has a second LinkedList that contains multiples of the objects, each with their own unique number ID. My problem is that if `"Test 0"`, `"Test 1"`, and `"Test 4"` are in this list and I try to add another object, that returns `"Test"`, it returns the wrong value (should be `"Test 2"`, aka the next incremental value). I tried using recursion to search the entire list each time there was a match to ensure no duplicates, but that still returns the wrong value.

The LinkedList `size()` method may be wrong, as I use a custom linked list, though for purposes of showing the code, it's easier to just say `LinkedList`. The `size()` in my custom list is the correct method for how many objects are stored within.

Shown with a `LinkedList` of type `String`, my code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     String test = "Test";
     int n = 0;

     LinkedList<String> testList = new LinkedList<String>();
     testList.add("Test 0");
     testList.add("Test 1");
     testList.add("Test 4");

     System.out.printf("Original List:%n");
     for(int i = 0; i < testList.size(); i++)
     {
          System.out.printf("%s%n", testList.get(i));
     }
     System.out.printf("%n%n");


     System.out.printf("%s%n", level(n, testList));
     testList.add(level(n, testList));

     System.out.printf("%s%n", level(n, testList));
     testList.add(level(n, testList));



     System.out.printf("New List:%n");
     for(int i = 0; i < testList.size(); i++)
     {
          System.out.printf("%s%n", testList.get(i));
     }
     System.out.printf("%n%n");
}


public static String level(int n, LinkedList<String> list)
{
     String test = "Test" + " " + Integer.toString(n);
     System.out.printf("Iteration: %d%nGenerated String: %s%n%n", n, test);

     for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
     {
          if(test.equals(list.get(i)))
          {
               n++;
               level(n, list);
          }
     }
     return test;
}
```

Oddly enough, the generated string through the recursive method is correct. It just doesn't return the correct value. The output is

```
Original List:
Test 0
Test 1
Test 4


Iteration: 0
Generated String: Test 0

Iteration: 1
Generated String: Test 1

Iteration: 2
Generated String: Test 2



Iteration: 0
Generated String: Test 0

Iteration: 1
Generated String: Test 1

Iteration: 2
Generated String: Test 2
```

For some reason, even though it generates `"Test 2"` on the first run through, it returns `"Test 0"`.

The modified list (when adding the 'leveled' numbers) is:

```
New List:
Test 0
Test 1
Test 4
Test 0
Test 0
```

It should return the `"Test 2"` on the first level, then on the second level, it should return `"Test 3"`. The output should look like:

```
New List:
Test 0
Test 1
Test 4
Test 2
Test 3
```

It should be that no matter where the next incremental digit is, it adds the correct one (ie, 2 and 4 are out of place, but it should still add 3 to the end).

Why is it returning the value `"Test 0"` even though it gets the correct value while in recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `level`, when you do

```
if(test.equals(list.get(i)))
{
    n++;
    level(n, list);
}
```

you are recursing (and dropping the result of the recursion). If, I change it to assign the result of recursion to `test` like

```
if(test.equals(list.get(i)))
{
    n++;
    test = level(n, list);
}
```

then I get

```
New List:
Test 0
Test 1
Test 4
Test 2
Test 3
```

Comment: I didn't even think to assign the result as result of the looping. Thank you, it does work.